# can't use curator 3.4.1 to delete logs in my ELK Version: 5.6.5

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-curator

I have ELK 5.6.5 and am trying as usual to use curator to delete old logs but but fails now.

```
curator --version
curator, version 3.4.1
```

I have used the command `$ sudo apt-get install elasticsearch-curator`  to install curator
 When running the curator command and the output as shown below :

```
ELK-5:~$ curator delete indices --older-than 14 --time-unit days --timestring %Y.%m.%d --regex '^logstash-'
2018-01-09 14:14:08,220 INFO      Job starting: delete indices
2018-01-09 14:14:08,223 ERROR     Expected Elasticsearch version range > 1.0.0 < 3.0.0
2018-01-09 14:14:08,223 ERROR     Incompatible with version 5.6.5 of Elasticsearch.
```

Any ideas how to get curator work, or another idea to delete old logs?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [version compatibility page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/version-compatibility.html) , curator 3.x is only for ES 1.x and ES 2.x.

You need curator 4 or 5 in order to have it working with Elasticsearch 5.x

The installation instruction for curator 4 or 5 can be seen [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/apt-repository.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have downloaded the package locally and installed it. and now curator working fine.